# Load script tag from the file html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the header of the first page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#register_reg").click(function(){
    $("#register_form").load("test_test.php #register_rules");
  });
});
</script>
```

In the content of the ID **#register_rules** in the second file (test_test.php)
there are this line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquerycode.js"></script>
```

The probleme is, 
in the fist page,  when i click the link (ID #register_reg) the line **script** not added in the ID **#register_form**

So, how I can add the content of the ID  #register_rules with here script in the ID #register_form

Comment: You can use getScript() to load the script and then run it - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the correct code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#register_reg").click(function(){
    $("#register_form").load("test_test.php #register_rules", function() { 
        $("#register_form").append("<script type='text/javascript' src='jquerycode.js'></" + "script>"); 
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The script is stripped out of the HTML loaded.

From the jQuery docs about load()  (emphasis added)

http://api.jquery.com/load/

> Script Execution
>
> When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector
>   expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being
>   removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. **If
>   .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL,
>   however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated**,
>   and thus are not executed. An example of both cases can be seen below:
>
> Here, any JavaScript loaded into #a as a part of the document will
>   successfully execute.
>
> 1 $( "#a" ).load( "article.html" ); However, in the following case,
>   script blocks in the document being loaded into #b are stripped out
>   and not executed:
>
> 1 $( "#b" ).load( "article.html #target" );

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$("#register_form").load("test_test.php #register_rules",function(){
    $.getScript("jquerycode.js"); 
});
```

Comment: not working, the function "append" working verry well